# Doubts about FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android

Hi i use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to export and import the database of my app.

For accident the person pressed the wrong button, so instead of exporting the files, he imported a old one.
Those files are scard files.

How can i find the old db file that was exported with FileOutputStream ?

is it possible for it to be im some kind of folder ?

Thanks

Comment: Not unless you created a backup.

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. Your question is not about programming but about system administration.  You might try the Server Fault site.  PS: Android is a version of linux.  PPS, as far as I know there is no "recycle bin" in the android File system.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter with which the FileOutputStream was instantiated. If it is a String, this is the name of the file to which the exported DB is being saved.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Export\\db.scard");
```

If this is a static name like the one in the example above, the old backup would be in all probability be overwritten and difficult(almost impossible) to recover. However, if it is dynamically generated like:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Export\\db_"+count+".scard");
```

where count is a unique variable, you should check the directory ( "C:\Export" in this fake example) for instances of previously generated db backups.

FileOutputStream can also be instantiated using a previously defined File or FileDescriptor object and you should look at their constructor arguments passed while creating them for the actual path where the backups are being stored.

Comment: Thanks for the help !